# method button for add latter on label

Tags: java, swing

I have the HangGame program I wont write this code when I Press any Latter Button like (A,B,..... ) the latter that I Pressed it will be appear in the right place of the label part of the word that I read it in the text file for example I read word in Text file like (Stake) and on the screen will appear five label (_ _ _ _ _ ) , when I hold S button the character S will appear on the first label part (S _ _ _ _ ) and so on... . I don't know how I write the code for the Action listener inside Button. finally I add Labels with out problem but I don't know how to put right character in the right place.
I hope you understand my problem.

```
    public void ButtonComponent () {
    for (int i = 65; i < 78; i++) {
        JButton temp = new JButton("" + (char) i);
        temp.addActionListener(new BtnListener());
        temp.setBounds((i - 64) * 55, 110, 50, 30);
        add(temp);
    }
    for (int i = 78; i < 91; i++) {
        JButton temp = new JButton("" + (char) i);
        temp.addActionListener(new BtnListener());
        temp.setBounds((i - 77) * 55, 150, 50, 30);
        add(temp);
    }
}
class BtnListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    for (int s=0;s<splitword.length;s++) {
    String btnText = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().toLowerCase();
    if (splitword[s].contains(btnText)) {
        System.out.println("This letter is contained in the word:" + btnText);
    }
```

Comment: can anyone solve my problem please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is Hangman, you will have to keep track of all correct letters used. Here is a template for a solution:

```
String guessWord = "STAKE";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("S"); // hint: btnText...
builder.append("T");
String displayWord = guessWord.replaceAll("[^" + builder.toString() + "]", "_");
```

I won't solve the problem outright but this should give you enough to work with.

Comment: I will try may be it's useful for me